# How to add elements to an array using Functional Programming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

enter code hereI am still trying to wrap my head around how this functional programming paradigm works. I have an array of parts names and I would like to add more names to the array if they meet the criteria. How do add the elements in a functional manner? Thank you for the help.

EDIT:
That was really quick feedback. 
Currently I don't have an array but just list of part names that I would like to put into an array if they meet the criteria. Not sure if this is going to make matters worse down the line but the parts themselves will be objects that will have the name, cost, and part number etc..

EDIT: This is what I eventually came up with. Not sure if it is the best but it is working for now. Please feel free to tell me where I can improve. I really want to understand the logic behind how and why we do things.

```
function isGroupTag(arr) {
    return arr.nodeName === "Group";
}

function makePartObject(xml) {
    return {
        rsn : getInnerHTMLValueOfChildren(xml, "MTR_COMP.RSN"),
        partNumber : getInnerHTMLValueOfChildren(xml, "MTR_COMP.PART_NO"),
        niin : getInnerHTMLValueOfChildren(xml, "MTR_COMP.NIIN"),
        fsc : getInnerHTMLValueOfChildren(xml, "MTR_COMP.FSC"),
        cost : getInnerHTMLValueOfChildren(xml, "MTR_COMP.COST")
    }
}

function getReport(xml, reportNumber) {
    report = xml.children[0].children[reportNumber].children[1].children[1].children[0];
    let partReport = report.children[1];
    // Create a part Array
    let arr = Array.from(report.children);
    // Filter out header and footer part of array
    let parts = arr.filter(isGroupTag);
    let partList = parts.map(function (x) { return makePartObject(x, partReport)});
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but this question feels a little bit like you are misunderstanding functional programming. The basic operations are still the same, the difference is that functions are used and chained in place of classes.

Comment: You are referring to the immutability principle. If you were altering your entries in the array, then it should return a new array (use map/filter/reduce for that). If you just add new entries to the existing array its fine.

Comment: Note that "adding to an array" and "functional programming" are mutually exclusive: you never alter something in place in FP. Functional languages (i.e. not JavaScript) use structural sharing to reduce the overhead of copying everything in the old data structure into the new one to make this feasible.

Comment: @JaredSmith You are exactly right. I am very new to functional programming and I am trying to understand it. I think maybe my wording was inaccurate, I was trying to build an array using functional programming not so much add to it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this?:

```
const partList = "tire, engine, chassis, transmission"
```

If so, then I would...

Create an array of all the parts:

```
const parts = partList.split(", ");
```

And filter that list:

```
const filteredParts = parts.filter((part) => {return criteria.includes(part)});
```